# How to know the state of Spark job

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2

Now I have a job running on amazon ec2 and I use putty to connect with the ec2 cluster,but just know the connection of putty is lost.After I reconnect with the ec2 cluster I have no output of the job,so I don't know if my job is still running.Anybody know how to check the state of Spark job?

thanks

Comment: Did you try to access the web UI on port 8080? You can also try to access the driver web UI on port 4040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are on yarn cluster, you could run 
    yarn application -list
 to get a list of appliactions and then run
    yarn application -status applicationId
 to know the status

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to use `GNU Screen` (or other similar tool) to keep session alive (but detached, if connection lost with machine) when working on remote machines.

The status of a Spark application can be ascertained from Spark UI (or Yarn UI).

If you are looking for cli command:

For stand-alone cluster use:

```
spark-submit --status <app-driver-id>
```

For yarn:

```
yarn application --status <app-id>
```